# ERROR Relation already exists in PostgreSQL when creating an index on a table

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have an error when running the the queries below on PostgreSQL from a Java code

```
 .....
 sql =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (s VARCHAR(100), p VARCHAR(100), o VARCHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY (s,p,o)) ; ";                   
 pgsql.runUpdateQuery(sql);         

 sql =  "CREATE INDEX indextable1 ON table1 (s,p,o);";  
 pgsql.runUpdateQuery(sql);         
 .....
```

But i got the following Error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "indextable1" already exists
```

Can someone explain me what its happening? My understanding is that `PRIMARY KEY` is consider to be an `INDEX` and therefore the second query fail. Am I right ?

Comment: There is another index (or table) named `indextable1` in your schema. It has nothing to do with the fact that the column list is already indexed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I've clean-up all the database before running again queries, now everything gone well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the primary key constraint name is equal the table name. I don know how postgres represents constraints, but I think the error "Relation already exists" was being triggered during the creation of the primary key constraint because the table was already declared. But because of this error, the table wasnt created at the end.